# I'm struggling with beta barrel refactor

Tags: python, linux, bioinformatics, biopython

I am new to programming and I'm trying to run a code
at the first command `python main.py -f [drslpa_fasta.txt]` I'm encountering the following error

```
Running 
Predicting structure for level 4
Clearing temp dir
Beta barrel membrane protein register prediction
Preparing input for register prediction...
No max_strand_len provided, using default value 12
Intervals : [(3, 6), (14, 17), (27, 31), (41, 45), (59, 65), (84, 90), (96, 100), (122, 130), (135, 144), (166, 177), (191, 202), (280, 291), (304, 315), (352, 361), (365, 376), (383, 389), (392, 399), (446, 454), (482, 493), (510, 521), (525, 536), (553, 564), (572, 583), (596, 607), (628, 639), (645, 655), (674, 680)]
TMregs : [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
------------------------PDB : Q9RRB6_SLPA
------------------------ec_raw_dir : /home/islem/BetaBarrelRefactor/sc.psicov
------------------------ No psicov file found for Q9RRB6_SLPA
Predicting registers...
Running :/home/islem/BetaBarrelRefactor/bb_register/pred_combine/exec/new_pred_reg_bestscore_ecparam110030080.out /home/islem/BetaBarrelRefactor/bb_register/tmp_files/default.test /home/islem/BetaBarrelRefactor/bb_register/tmp_files/scores.ecs /home/islem/BetaBarrelRefactor/bb_register/pred_combine/odds /home/islem/BetaBarrelRefactor/inputs 4 > /home/islem/BetaBarrelRefactor/bb_register/tmp_files/results.l04 &
Running level 4
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Optimizing local register for better global shear...
/home/islem/BetaBarrelRefactor/bb_register/tmp_files 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 52, in <module>
    run_register_prediction([pdb], l)
  File "/home/islem/BetaBarrelRefactor/bb_register/main.py", line 52, in run_register_prediction
    get_shear_adjustments(test_file_path, TMP_DIR, outfile)
  File "/home/islem/BetaBarrelRefactor/bb_register/shear_adjustment/get_all.py", line 17, in get_shear_adjustments
    shear_adjust(testfile_path, prediction_results_path, opt, outfile )
  File "/home/islem/BetaBarrelRefactor/bb_register/shear_adjustment/new_reg_adjust.py", line 576, in shear_adjust
    cand1, cand0 = sorted(strandpairs)[-2:]
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

to note that the same code has been successfully executed with another file. 
Please, could anyone help me to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`sorted(strandpairs)[-2:]` is an empty list. This happens if `strandpairs` is also an empty list. Then you ask to unpack (or split) an empty list in two variables: `cand1` and `cand2`, but the data doesn't match.

```
>>> a, b = []
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
>>> a, b = [1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
>>> a, b = [1, 2] # This works
```

Comment: This means `strandpairs`, whatever it is, should be a list with two elements in it, but there's none. It can be due to a faulty input, to a bug in `new_reg_adjust.py`, or many other reasons. That's all I can say with the info you gave.

Comment: Looking at the code (https://github.com/nerrull/BetaBarrelRefactor), the more probable cause is a faulty input file. It requires a line starting with `## `, followed by values separated by spaces/tabs, and then by ":", e.g. `## 1:2.5 4:3.5`. Your input probably has a line with only two `##`, but nothing after them.